# Divolte session don't time out within a page-view if window time beyond the session timeout (default 30 minutes)

Tags: javascript, websocket, divolte

Hi team can you guide me on this divolte issue
https://github.com/divolte/divolte-collector/issues/163

I am writing here actually that Divolte repository has been archived by the owner.

1. When a session is created and there is no activity (i-e no events/tags generated from the client .js) during a window time beyond the session timeout (default 30 minutes), the session id is not regenerated for the next event while it should be.
2. and I want TO FORCE_CLOSE my session as well so the user can force close it any time whenever they want before the time and intimate the server for the same that session is closed by user, so calculate the loss

If anybody guide me on this , this would be really helpful
If anybody wants to refer another open source library for tracking events then also please suggest

this would be really helpful